# Regex matching substring inside curly brackets inside script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the information between the brackets, but my pattern doesn't find a match.

The pattern I'm using is

```
/var\scool=(.*);<\/script>/;
```

The sample text:

```
<script>
  var cool={
  //stuff in here
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Use [`/var\scool=([\s\S]*);\s*<\/script>/`](https://regex101.com/r/yT4zX2/1).

Comment: You can try /{(.)+^}}/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that worked! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @JohnAyers: I posted the suggestion with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have has a dot with a `*` quantifier (`.*`) that matches *zero or more characters other than a newline, as many as possible*. In JavaScript regex, to match any character including a newline you can use `[^]` or `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]`.

The other problem is that there is whitespace between the `;` and `</script>`, thus a `\s*` is necessary.

Use

```
/var\scool=([\s\S]*);\s*<\/script>/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT4zX2/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
/var\scool\=(.*);\s<\/script>/s
```